# xmpp pubsub understanding

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

The subscriber will only receive content from the moment he is subscripting to a node and all old content published by publisher will not be received by subscriber.  Is this correct?  May i know, what do i need to do in order for subscriber to receive all previous old content ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure your nodes to be persistent or transient. According to the [specifictaion (XEP-0060)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html):

> Whether the node is persistent or transient is determined by the "pubsub#persist_items" configuration field.

However, your pubsub service (or server) might be configured to ignore persistence of events. (If you're using Openfire, I think there is a configurable limit for the maximum total size of stored items)

As I know you are using [smackx-pubsub](http://wiki.github.com/squaremo/smackx-pubsub), here's some code:

```
// create new node
pubSubManager.createNode(nodeId, newConfigureForm(persistent, includePayload, accessModel)

// change existing node
node.sendConfigurationForm(newConfigureForm(persistent, includePayload, accessModel));

private ConfigureForm newConfigureForm(final boolean persistent, final boolean includePayload, final AccessModel accessModel) {
  final ConfigureForm form = new ConfigureForm(FormType.submit);
  form.setPersistentItems(persistent);
  form.setDeliverPayloads(includePayload);
  form.setAccessModel(accessModel);
  return form;
}
```

PS: Can you tell me why I get the feeling that we're doing a kind of pair programming here? ;)

Comment: @cometta and @sfussenegger - You left out that to get the old items, you have to do a node.getItems().  Also, instead of the github version you should build Smack from it's source (http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp) to get the latest version of the pubsub code.

Comment: @Robin so pubsub is finally coming out of the box? starting from version 3.2?